# What is the name of this set with projectiles and large gray wheels?

Tags: set-identification

What is the name of this set? It appears to be castle or medieval themed.

[image: phone screenshot of the assembled set]

Answer (score 10):

It is set 7020 named [Army of Vikings with Heavy Artillery Wagon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=63993#T=S&O=%7B"iconly":0%7D)

[image]

Comment: A great set: army builder, totally fun launching mechanism